# If else OR statement in Assembly?

Tags: if-statement, assembly, arm, cortex-m

Confused on using branching commands in Assembly, mostly just `BNE`, and `BEQ`.
So I have to write an assembly code for the pseudo-code:

```
X = 5, Y = 10, Z = 15

if X != 4 && Y == 10 || Z = 20 

A = X + Y - 2

else   R = Z - 5 + X
```

I'm coding in **Keil uVision5 for an ARM Cortex M0 Plus** (No clue if this is needed info) within its low registers which are R0-R7 for this specific board.

I know how I'd write the `if else` statement itself but I'm mainly asking how I'd go about with the `OR` part of the code. Obvious `X!=4` is true, and `Y==10` would be true,  and then check if `Z = 20` which is false, so would I check if `X!=4` first, jump using a `BNE` label to check Y, use a `BEQ` to check Z, which is false, but since the equation is true already I'd jump to a `BNE` endif statement for `A=X+Y-2`?

and then in between with no label in front of it I'd write the else statement for the assembler to go to if the first BNE label was somehow false..?

```
A EQU 0x2000000
R EQU 0x2000004
X EQU 0x2000008
Y EQU 0x200000C
Z EQU 0x2000010

 LDR R7, =X
 LDR R0, [R7]
 ADD R0, #5  ; X = 5 in R0
 CMP R0, #4  ; Compare X != 4
 BNE jumpToY

jumpToY
 LDR R7, =Y
 LDR R1, [R7]   ; Y = 10 in R1
 CMP R1, #10    ; Compare Y == 10
 BEQ jumpToZ

jumpToZ
 etc...
```

Comment: Jump to the fail target as soon as a test fails.

Comment: Sorry I'm still a beginner with assembly, how would I go about to branch to the fail target (that means the else statement correct..?) in the code. @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: With a jump instruction. Which you skip if the test passes.

Comment: In assembly language, `GOTO` is **not** [considered harmful](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html).

Comment: Just to be sure, can you put parenethesis around your orignal psuedo code so that we know for sure the order of your and and or.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How asm works in general for processors that use flags set by one instruction then a branch or jump on condition instruction.  At some point before the branch/jump on condition you set the flags, the compare for example does this in this case.  The way the branch on condition instruction works is if the condition is true it branches to that address exactly the way a goto works in C.  if the condition is not true then it does not.

```
if(x!=4) goto label0;
label2:
if(z==20) goto label1;
R = Z - 5 + X;
goto done;
label0:
if(y!=10) goto label2:
...
done:
```

so from the top if x is not four then we branch to label0 and do what is there, if it is four then we keep going and do the if z==20
then refocus on the z==20 if z==20 then goto label1 else keep going and do the math.

in assembly that would be something like

```
ldr r0,=X
ldr r0,[r0]
cmp r0,#4
bne label0

ldr r2,=Z
ldr r2,[r2]
cmp r2,#20
beq label1

sub r2,#5
add r0,r2
ldr r2,=X
str r0,[r2]
b done

label0:
ldr r1,=Y
ldr r1,[r1]
cmp r1,#10
bne label2:

...

done:
```

I put spaces after the branches for no particular reason.  on that first bne label0 if that does happen then we next execute what is after label 0 the loading of the y address if the equal flag was set then we dont branch and we keep going and execute the load of Z address.

as far as covering the logic paths maybe make a truth table for yourself a true or false for each of X!=4 Y==10 and Z==20 and the result is either R= or A=, then from that you can worst case execute the truth table literally (8 sets of comparisons) or narrow it down...and keep optimizing until you are happy.

Ultimately you want the A=  code somewhere with a branch to the end of the function and the R= code somewhere also with a branch to the end of the function, then based on your truth table and implementation you create paths to get to the A= or R= code, but you must hit one or the other.

EDIT:

note your first three lines look wrong

```
 LDR R7, =X
 LDR R0, [R7]
 ADD R0, #5  ; X = 5 in R0
```

that is not setting X to 5 as your comment implies it ADDS 5 to X so whatever X was you added 5.

If you want to implement this X = 5, Y = 10, Z = 15

```
ldr r1,=X
mov r0,#5
str r0,[r1]
ldr r1,=Y
mov r0,#10
str r0,[r1]
ldr r1,=Z
mov r0,#15
str r0,[r1]
```

THEN get x and compare it

```
LDR R7, =X
LDR R0, [R7]
CMP R0, #4  ; Compare X != 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Think about how you go about evaluating logical conditions in your head. If you want A or B and you get A then you don't need to think about B. If you want A and B and you don't have A then there's no point in calculating B.

There are the purists who argue that you should evaluate both conditions and then use a logical comparison on the results: 
Calculate A
Calculate B
AND/OR the results together

Fortunately, the engineering approach won out:

For A AND B (assuming BEQ is "true"):

```
Calculate A
BNE fail
Calculate B
BNE fail
success:
   ...
   RET/JMP somewhere  ; Don't drop through into fail
fail:
   ...
```

For A OR B (again, assuming BEQ is "true"):

```
Calculate A
BEQ success
Calculate B
BNE fail
success:
   ...
   RET/JMP somewhere  ; Don't drop through into fail
fail:
   ...
```

Comment: This is an ARM question: there *is* a way to OR conditions together efficiently, using predication: e.g. `cmp r0,#1` / `cmpne r0, #7` / `cmpne r0, #11` sets Z if `r0 == any of 1, 7, 11`.  The `ne` predication makes the later `cmp` instructions act like a `nop` if the Z flag was already set by one of the earlier `cmp` instructions.  Branchlessly evaluating all the conditions is good for *short* chains where that's cheap. (And where where the first one alone would short-circuit evaluation most of the time. Putting the most-common skip condition first is a good optimization if it's predictable.)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It's been a while since I used assembler and I'm not a RISC expert but thanks for the information. From what I've seen, I regret not getting my hands on an Archimedes back in the day.

Comment: This is unique to 32-bit ARM, not RISC in general.  ARM isn't all that RISCy in some ways.  It's a load-store machine with many RISC-like qualities, but they chose to be non-RISCy when it made sense (e.g. a push/pop-multiple instructions which have to be microcoded.  But PowerPC has those too...)  Using 4 bits of the instruction word for predication on the condition codes (with ALways being the no-predication encoding) is unique, and introduces a dependency on the previous flag-setting instruction (for predicates other than ALways or never=NOP), but there's another bit to control flag-setting.

Comment: AArch64 dropped predication support, leaving only a few conditional instructions like CSEL and CSINC (conditional select increment) which is your classic ALU-select operation, not like NOPing out a load or store to an invalid pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
A EQU 0x2000000
R EQU 0x2000004
X EQU 0x2000008
Y EQU 0x200000C
Z EQU 0x2000010
```

Here, you can see conditional instructions to prevent extra jumping.  We check the first 2 cases of the And first, then default to the Or case.  Notice also we have to jump beyond the else code to prevent both from executing.  Also notice we fall through to the else case, also to prevent an extra jump.

```
 ; These could be loaded with a singl LDM instruction instead.
 LDR R7, =X
 LDR R0, [R7]
 LDR R7, =Y
 LDR R0, [R7]
 LDR R7, =Z
 LDR R2, [R7]

 CMP R0,#5
 CMPEQ R1,#10
 BEQ FirstCase

 CMP R2,#5
 BEQ FirstCase
 ;... Fall Through

ElseCase:
   ...
   j RestOfCode
FirstCase:
   ...

RestOfCode:
```

Please beware I coded this in the blind, a dangerous thing to do for any language, ASM even more so.  It should demosntrate how to handle the And/Or cases you wanted to see though.

You can also drop your code into a C compiler and examine the output as it will show you working code as well.